# Coefficients of formal power series

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions, power-series

Given the power series

$$A(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \left ( x^{3n+1} - x^{3n} \right )$$

I want to determine the coefficients $a_n$ with $ A(x) = \sum_{n>=0} a_n x^n$

What can i do here? My first attempt was

$ A(x) = \sum_{n>=0}   \ (x^{2n+1}-x^{2n}) x^n$
But clearly a_n cant be dependant on x

I have also tried putting in x values and tried to determine a patter, but the series diverges, so i dont know what else to do?

Comment: Try writing down the first few terms of the sequence, and see if you can see the pattern

Comment: @1Rock has the right idea. Look for something like $-1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, \dots$